# Добавление значения в cookie-массив

Tags: php

Есть переменная `$Cur`, нужно записывать её значения в cookie-массив. Пробую так:

```
setcookie("CookieArray[".$k."]", $Cur); 
$newArray = $_COOKIE["CookieArray"];
$k = count($newArray);
$k++;
var_dump($newArray); //array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" }
```

Но каждый раз значение в `$newArray` перезаписывается, а нужно, чтобы оно добавлялось в следующий ключ массива.

Comment: Так может сначала надо `$k` получить, прежде чем его использовать для записи следующей переменной в куки?

Comment: Запишите все куки в один массив php, после чего этот массив сохраняйте в куки.
Писать так, как вы написали, неправильно.

Comment: @Visman спасибо, исправил!

Comment: @mix как это сделать?

Comment: @Никита `$cook['a'] = 'a'; $cook['b'] = 'b'; setcookie("array", $cook);`

Comment: @mix это не подходит, так как массив динамически изменяется.

Comment: @Никита что вам мешает динамически изменять массив?

Comment: @mix всё получилось!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$s_arr = serialize($arr); // где $arr Ваш массив
setcookie("array", $s_arr);
```

для вывода

```
$uns_arr = unserialize($_COOKIE["array"]);
var_dump($uns_arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Прошу прощения, но ваше условие - это взрыв мозга для меня. Разберитесь с постановкой задачи. Дело в том, что переменная $k - не существует при следующем вызове скрипта. Т.е. она каждый раз создается новая. Если вы хотите каждый раз прибавлять к ней единицу, то нужно ее передать, например, в качестве значения COOKIE. Вот пример реализации:

```
    if(isset($_COOKIE["k"]){
        $k = $_COOKIE["k"];
    } else {
        $k = 0;
    }

    setcookie("CookieArray[".$k."]", $Cur);
    $newArray = $_COOKIE["CookieArray"];
    $k++;
    setcookie("k", $k);
    var_dump($newArray);
```